# I wrote a code in C language to print passed/not passed on basis of his marks. No matter, what I input, I am getting the same results i.e passed

Tags: c

```
# include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    
    int marks;
    printf("enter marks: ");
    scanf("enter marks: %d ", &marks);

    if(marks > 30)
    {
        printf("passed");

    }

    else
    {
        printf("not");
    }
    
    return 0;

}
```

The criteria that I put doesn't help in the output, even if enter marks as 14, then too it displays passed. I am a beginner, so please help.

Comment: `scanf("enter marks: %d ", &marks);` should be `scanf("%d", &marks);`

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should never ever use `scanf` and friends or also other IO functions without checking the return value for expected result. In your case you would get `0` and know that input failed.

Comment: Please do not "**fix**" the code in the question ever.

Comment: @IłyaBursov I edited the code as you said, still the same problem.

Comment: Don't edit the code with fixed version, invalidating existing answers. Ask a new question with the new code.

Comment: But, if the fix doesn't work, you made some other mistake, such as not saving file, or running old binary after compiling, or something.

Comment: @Tejas18 probably you forgot to recompile, fixed code obviously works just fine https://onlinegdb.com/NvYkygpz4x

Answer (score 2):

```
printf("enter marks: ");
scanf("enter marks: %d ", &marks);
```

Is not correct.

You do not put a "prompt" in `scanf`.  Only the value you want to read.

It should be:

```
scanf("%d", &marks);  // Prompt was already done with printf on prior line
```

Comment: You also shouldn't have the space after `%d`.